# Is the order of fields in an entry in a .bib file important for printing the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

This example

```
@book{schleiermacher:hermeneutica,
 author = {Schleiermacher, Friedrich Daniel Ernst},
 year = {2001},
 title = {Hermeneutica},
 publisher = {Polirom},
 isbn = {973-683-617-7},
 location = {Iași},
 translator   = {Râmbu, Nicolae},
 introduction = {Râmbu, Nicolae},
 commentator  = {Râmbu, Nicolae},
 series = {Collegium}
}
```

Observe that the `translator`, `introduction` and `commentator` fields are the same person.

Q: Does changing the order of the fields in a given entry affect the printing of the bibliography, or is printing passed through `lbx` localisation ie: `bytranslatoranin` (biblatex) and `cbytranslatoranin` (biblatex-chicago)?

Comment: The order in the `.bib` file does not matter. The 'combined' string is 'calculated' by `biblatex` macros that don't know about the order in the `.bib` file: They will always choose the same hard-coded order. (I don't have time to check the details of the hard-coded order now, but I can write an answer with more details later.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for the explanation. I performed a change of order and nothing happened, indeed. I just wanted to be sure in case that was a particular case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the order in which you give fields in the `.bib` entry do not matter. (With BibTeX the order in which you give entire entries in the `.bib` file matters if you use the `crossref` feature: entries that are `crossref`ed must come *after* entries that `crossref` it.) It is no different in this case, the order in which you give the names in the `.bib` entry does not matter. The 'combined' string is 'calculated' by `biblatex` macros that don't know about the order in the `.bib` file at all: They get the info from the `.bbl` file, which knows nothing about the order in the `.bib` file and will always choose the same hard-coded order.

The relevant macros from `biblatex.def` are

```
\newbibmacro*{editor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{editortype}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{editor}}
     }
       {\def\abx@tempa{editors}}
       {\def\abx@tempa{editor}}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{editor}}
     }
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}s}}
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{translator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{translator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{commentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{commentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{annotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{annotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{introduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{introduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{foreword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{foreword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{editor}{afterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{afterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext[editortype]{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}}


\newbibmacro*{translator+othersstrg}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumgreater{\value{translator}}{1}}
    or
    test {\ifandothers{translator}}
  }
    {\def\abx@tempa{translators}}
    {\def\abx@tempa{translator}}%
  \ifnamesequal{translator}{commentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \clearname{commentator}}
    {\ifnamesequal{translator}{annotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \clearname{annotator}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{translator}{introduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \clearname{introduction}}
    {\ifnamesequal{translator}{foreword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \clearname{foreword}}
       {\ifnamesequal{translator}{afterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \clearname{afterword}}
          {}}}%
  \printtext[translatortype]{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}}


\newbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{editortype}
    {\def\abx@tempa{byeditor}}
    {\edef\abx@tempa{by\thefield{editortype}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{translator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{translator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{commentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{commentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{annotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{annotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{introduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{introduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{foreword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{foreword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{editor}{afterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{afterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}}}

\newbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{%
  \def\abx@tempa{bytranslator}%
  \ifnamesequal{translator}{commentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \clearname{commentator}}
    {\ifnamesequal{translator}{annotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \clearname{annotator}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{translator}{introduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \clearname{introduction}}
    {\ifnamesequal{translator}{foreword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \clearname{foreword}}
       {\ifnamesequal{translator}{afterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \clearname{afterword}}
          {}}}%
  \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}
```

and they will always choose the same hard-coded order

- `editor(s)<tr><co|an><in|fo|af>`
- `translator(s)<co|an><in|fo|af>`
- `byeditor(s)<tr><co|an><in|fo|af>`
- `bytranslator(s)<co|an><in|fo|af>`

Note that by far not all (combinatorically) possible combined roles are defined by default, if you need those you will have to define the strings and tweak the relevant macros to take the new strings into account.

Comment: I didn't know that `crossrefed must come after entries that crossref it.` Is this documented in biblatex.pdf? I intend to use `crossref`

Comment: @Mafsi The order of `crossref`ed and `crossref`ing entry is only important if you use BibTeX (and is documented in the BibTeX manual http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf, p. 3). If you use `biblatex` with Biber you don't need to worry about that, so this is not mentioned in the `biblatex` docs (since the `biblatex` docs assume you use Biber).