# Trying to reproduce entry fields for a multivolume book (best practice?)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

[image]

Translation of the red square is this:

```
Translation by Ionuț Bița
Edition, notes and commentaries by Nelu Zugravu
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{berstein:ist:eur,
  maintitle    = {Istoria Europei},
  title        = {Moștenirea Antichității},
  author       = {Berstein, Serge and Milza, Pierre},
  year         = {1997},
  publisher    = {Institutul European},
  location     = {Iași},
  series       = {Sinteze},
  volume       = {1},
  isbn         = {973-586-027-9},
  volumes      = {5},
  translator   = {Bița, Ionuț},
  editor      = {Zugravu, Nelu},
  editortype  = {\bibstring{editor}, \bibstring{annotations} and \bibstring{bycommentator}},
  pagetotal    = {372}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm interested in particular if is used correctly `editortype` or is a different way to put that explanations without:

```
editor      = {Zugravu, Nelu},
annotator   = {Zugravu, Nelu},
commentator = {Zugravu, Nelu},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle I'd prefer the version with

```
editor       = {Zugravu, Nelu},
annotator    = {Zugravu, Nelu},
commentator  = {Zugravu, Nelu},
```

even though it looks a bit repetitive in the input.

The problem with that is that `biblatex` then chooses the order in which it puts these roles in the bibliography. This order may be different from the order on the title page of the work you are citing. Furthermore, while `biblatex` has some support for combined roles, not all possible combinations are supported out of the box, so you may find that some things get split up unexpectedly. (See also the discussion at the end of my answer to [Is the order of fields in an entry in a .bib file important for printing the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580521/35864.)) If either of that bothers you, you can indeed force a particular description with

```
editor      = {Zugravu, Nelu},
editortype  = {<exact discription here>},
```

`editortype` can either be the identifier of a bibstring (like `editortype = {editor}` or `editortype = {editortrco},`) or free-form text (which may or may not include `\bibstring` calls). The problem with giving a free-form text is that the text cannot be changed easily to work in different contexts. `biblatex` sometimes puts the role after the name (`editor` and friends)

> Zugravu, Nelu (editor)

and sometimes before the name (`byeditor` and friends)

> edited by Nelu Zugravu

a hard-coded `editorstring` might not work for both situations. That said, you can often be pretty sure as to how the info will appear in the bibliography (in our case, we can be very confident it's going to be before the name).

I probably wouldn't use

```
editortype = {\bibstring{editor}, \bibstring{annotations} and \bibstring{bycommentator}},
```

because it mixes the two types of bibstrings (before and after the name). You can see that this goes wrong if you load `biblatex` with the option `abbreviate=false`. Then we get

> Editor, annotations and commented by Nelu Zugravu

which doesn't look right.

The usage of `and` together with `\bibstring` commands also looks odd, because the strings will be translated, but not the `and`. If I switch to German I get

> Hrsg., Erläut. and komm. von Nelu Zugravu.

which has an untranslated "and" (should be "und" in German) and wrong capitalisation because it mixes the two types of strings.

So if you want to go down the `editortype` route, I'd suggest you either just hard-code the string you want to see (which then cannot be translated etc.) or you define a new bibliography string and use that

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{byeditoranco}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  byeditoranco = {edited, annotated\finalandcomma\ and commented by},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{berstein:ist:eur:hardcode,
  maintitle    = {Istoria Europei},
  title        = {Moștenirea Antichității},
  author       = {Berstein, Serge and Milza, Pierre},
  year         = {1996},
  publisher    = {Institutul European},
  location     = {Iași},
  series       = {Sinteze},
  volume       = {1},
  isbn         = {973-586-027-9},
  volumes      = {5},
  translator   = {Bița, Ionuț},
  editor       = {Zugravu, Nelu},
  editortype   = {\autocap{e}dited, annotated and commented by},
  pagetotal    = {372}
}
@mvbook{berstein:ist:eur:names,
  maintitle    = {Istoria Europei},
  title        = {Moștenirea Antichității},
  author       = {Berstein, Serge and Milza, Pierre},
  year         = {1997},
  publisher    = {Institutul European},
  location     = {Iași},
  series       = {Sinteze},
  volume       = {1},
  isbn         = {973-586-027-9},
  volumes      = {5},
  translator   = {Bița, Ionuț},
  editor       = {Zugravu, Nelu},
  annotator    = {Zugravu, Nelu},
  commentator  = {Zugravu, Nelu},
  pagetotal    = {372}
}
@mvbook{berstein:ist:eur:string,
  maintitle    = {Istoria Europei},
  title        = {Moștenirea Antichității},
  author       = {Berstein, Serge and Milza, Pierre},
  year         = {1998},
  publisher    = {Institutul European},
  location     = {Iași},
  series       = {Sinteze},
  volume       = {1},
  isbn         = {973-586-027-9},
  volumes      = {5},
  translator   = {Bița, Ionuț},
  editor       = {Zugravu, Nelu},
  editortype   = {editoranco},
  pagetotal    = {372}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Serge Berstein and Pierre Milza. Istoria Europei. Vol. 1: Mostenirea Antichitatii. Edited, annotated, and commented by Nelu Zugravu. Trans. by Ionut Bita. 5 vols. Sinteze. Iasi: Institutul European, 1998. 372 pp. isbn: 973-586-027-9.]

Comment: Excellent answer, as always! Please tell me something:
`1.` in `romanian.lbx` it is sufficient to declare `byeditoranco = {edited, annotated\finalandcomma\ and commented by},
}` to be compiled or are more things to do to the `.lbx`? and `2.` (a little bit offtopic) I saw that biblatex project is somewhere at 80% so I assume that a next release will be produced. If I want to make some modification after that release and check some translation is it sufficient to override in miktek the file or should (as I'm doing now) to put it in the work folder?

Comment: @Mafsi 1. In an `.lbx` file you would generally use the form `<string> = {{<long>}{<short>}},` to translate a string. If the string hasn't been defined yet, it would also have to be declared with `\NewBibliographyString`. 2. I don't know where you found the 80% but I don't expect a new release shortly. We usually only release when enough new stuff has built up, unless there are bugs that need to be fixed we usually have at least a couple of months between releases. The last release was 2020-12-31, so I'm not expecting anything before March.

Comment: ... Generally I'd advise against overwriting files controlled by your TeX system. There are ways to install your own versions of files locally (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/35864) and for testing the document directory usually suffices.